# How to Add C,C++ libraries into my j2ee Application

Tags: jakarta-ee

I would like to add C,C++ libraries into my j2ee application. Is there any kind of information regarding these, if anybody has solutions please let me give the guidence.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Java can't call C/C++ directly, you need to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Here is a very simple "Hello world" example using JNI:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add c, c++ or any other natively compiled code into a J2EE application. You need first to create a [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) wrapper over these libraries and then add them to the Java application.